# Protected property is not accessible if defined as abstract

Tags: matlab

Using Matlab R2012a, I have the following class hierarchy:

```
classdef Parent < handle
  properties (Abstract, SetAccess = protected)
    Limit
  end
end

classdef SimpleChild < Parent
  properties (SetAccess = protected)
    Limit = 1.0
  end
end

classdef ExtendedChild < Parent
  properties (Access = private)
    Child = SimpleChild
  end
  properties (Dependent, SetAccess = protected)
    Limit
  end
  methods
    function this = ExtendedChild
      this.Limit = 2;
    end
    function output = get.Limit(this)
      output = this.Child.Limit;
    end
    function set.Limit(this,input)
      this.Child.Limit = input;
    end
  end
end
```

This a simple example where the "Parent" class defines an abstract "Limit" property, which is implemented in both the "SimpleChild" and the "ExtendedChild" class. The "ExtendedChild" class encapsulates a private instance on the "SimpleChild" class and forward the access methods (get/set) to the private instance. Constructing an "ExtendedChild" instance fails with the following message:

```
>> obj = ExtendedChild
Setting the 'Limit' property of the 'SimpleChild' class is not allowed.

Error in ExtendedChild/set.Limit (line 16)
      this.Child.Limit = input;

Error in ExtendedChild (line 10)
      this.Limit = 2;
```

I would have expected the "Limit" property to be settable since it is defined in the "Parent" class with a protected SetAccess. I can make the problem disappear if the property is implemented directly in the "Parent" class, but then I cannot redefine it as dependent in the "ExtendedChild" class, which is the point of the construction (separation of interface and implementation).

Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Limit` property of `SimpleChild` is `protected`, you can only set its value from `SimpleChild` or a subclass of `SimpleChild`, which is not the case for `ExtendedChild`.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, so can't really advise on what the "best" way to do it might be. But I would guess that whatever you want, it's unlikely that having a `set` method for a `Dependent` property is the right way to achieve it - there are only very rare reasons why you might want to do that.

Comment: Sam, thanks for your answer.

I'm currently developing a framework where I need a entire class hierarchy to have a specific property (Limit in this example) where any instance of the hierarchy can modify that property on another instance.

I think I'm confused by the fact that it works for methods but apparently not for properties. If you would define an abstract protected method on the Parent class, then an instance of ExtendedChild could call that method on an instance of SimpleChild.